# upgrade grub 0.97 to grub2 in opensuse 11.3

Tags: grub2, grub, opensuse

I want to update grub on my opensuse 11.3 machine from 0.97 to grub2
this is how it looks like when i invoke grub-install
can anyone help me out here on how to upgrade to grub2

```
vm@machine:/usr/sbin# grub-install -V
WARNING! You are trying to invoke the unsupported grub-install script
with a parameter. To really do this, call grub-install.unsupported.
You should rather call "yast2 bootloader" or create configuration files
appropriate for the intended target
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my machine has a opensuse 11.3 and it has legacy grub, i would like to upgrade it to grub2 how can we do that ?

Comment: I think it is time to upgrade your install, not just grub. The support for openSUSE 11.3 ended January 20th 2012 after over 18 months of lifetime. https://en.opensuse.org/Archive:Portal:11.3